How does the largest eigenvalue of symmetric matrix associated with a quadratic form change with dimension n.
This is likely not the smartest question but I just wanted to ask if someone could explain why the Lipschitz constant of a quadratic $x^TAx$ where A has entries randomly generated from the Uniform distribution U(-1,1) and  domain constrained by a hypercube $[-1,1]^n$ appears to grow with $\sqrt n$ of the dimension n (I run a few experiments). I think there must be a connection between this and the fact that the maximum distance between two points in a hypercube is also a function of $\sqrt n$ but I can't see the exact link.

This appears to be a non-trivial problem, an overview of similar questions is in https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02928

Thank you @Steen82

I haven't manged to find the answer for the Uniform distribution but I thought I will just add the result for distributions with variance 1 and mean 0:
C. Bordenave, P. Caputo, D. Chafaï, and K. Tikhomirov, On the spectral radius of a random matrix: an
upper bound without fourth moment, Ann. Probab. 46 (2018), no. 4, 2268–2286. MR 3813992
A result for Distributions with further relaxed requirements also exits:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05484#:~:text=Consider%20a%20square%20matrix%20with,square%20root%20of%20the%20dimension.
It seems for those distributions the spectral radius of A (which here is equal to the Lipschitz constant) is not only proportional to $\sqrt n $ but converges to exactly $\sqrt n $ as n grows.
